Help menu footers are hard to read in dark mode
While reading in the help center, specifically the misleading information policy, I was scrolling through and saw that the footer was light gray on white. I use dark mode on this site so this was kind of hard for me to read. This bug happens on many pages accessible from the code of conduct page, including:

Abusive behavior policy
Sensitive content and imagery policy
Self-harm and suicide
Harmful political content policy
Misleading information policy
Disruptive use of tooling policy
Inauthentic usage policy



possible regression of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398296/997587
